# Converting spatial data to table of vertices using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a spatial data table in PostGIS 2.1 that looks like this:

```
Geom                | type |  cost    
POLYGON(0 0,1 1,2 2)|  A   | 123
POLYGON(3 3,4 4,5 5)|  b   | 123
```

I am trying to create a view of this table that looks like this for a system that does not support spatial data natively:

```
vertexorder  |  x  |  y  | type  |  Cost    
1            | 0   | 0   |   A   | 123
2            | 1   | 1   |   A   | 123
3            | 2   | 2   |   A   | 123
1            | 3   | 3   |   b   | 123
2            | 4   | 4   |   b   | 123
3            | 5   | 5   |   b   | 123
```

Is there anyway to query for vertex like this?

Comment: This example is flawed by incorrect ring construction -- **4** points is the minimum to assemble a valid polygon (the first vertex must repeated, and all 4 points may not fall in a line)

Comment: I know but it was late and once i was in bed and realized the PC seems too far away to correct it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  (points).path vertexorder, 
ST_X((points).geom) x, ST_Y((points).geom), 
type, cost 
FROM (SELECT ST_DumpPoints(geom) points, type, cost FROM my_table) a;
```

Ok, now tested, this should work.

Note the parenthesizes arount points in

```
(points).path
```

and

```
ST_X((points).geom), ST_Y((points).geom)
```